# Web Client API and Rest API

Tags: java, api, exchangewebservices

As I have understood we use Web services(Rest/Soap) so that a piece of code with some functionality written in one language(say Java) can be used by other programmer no matter the language(say Python) he is developing the application over the internet.

One of the projects I came across uses EWS web services to create,delete appointments on our Outlook 365. The application is developed in Java and a JAVA EWSAPI.jar file is included in the library path(which contains class files like appointment.class,Meeting.class etc) to connect to EWS server and create meetings .

My confusion is suppose we were developing the application in Python, so for that do we have another API (say EWSPython.pythonextension). So then how developing a web service helped us.

I understand API defines the set the methods available and how can they be called with argument.

Please clear my doubts.

Comment: REST and SOAP have strong differences, REST only 'basic' updates on objects, SOAP can execute methods (f.e. business methods etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAVA EWSAPI.jar file  is a API Client Library.

What is a client library?
A client library, sometimes called a helper library, is a set of code that application developers can add to their development projects. It provides chunks of code that do the basic things an application needs to do in order to interact with the API. For example, a client library may:

Provide boiler-plate code needed to create an HTTP request and to process the HTTP response from the API.

Include classes that correspond with the elements or data types that the API expects. For example, a Java client library can return native Java objects in the response from the API.
Handle user authentication and authorisation.
How is that useful?
Looking at the developer who’s using the API: With a REST API or any web service API, the developer could be using any of a number of programming languages to make the API calls.

Wouldn’t it be great if we could give them some code in their own language, to help them get started with the API? That’s what a client library does. It helps to reduce the amount of code the application developers have to write, and ensures they’re using the API in the best supported manner.

For more information:
https://ffeathers.wordpress.com/2015/10/25/what-is-an-api-client-library/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have misunderstood the  aim of webservices. We need webservices   to make their calls (clients) a platform independent interface which means that once you have created your webservice  using any technology (java for your case here) now anyone can call this service by creating a client using any language like python, C#, C++, Ruby, ........... in that case a service which was built by Java will be consumed or called by an application or client created using python and vice versa.